# jQuery validation engine js daterange custom function needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, jquery-validation-engine

Am using the following validation plugin: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I have two fields start date and end date.

I want the start date to choose any future/past dates. However, I want the end date to compare with start date and it should be able to choose same date and future dates only based on the start date.

So, if I select start date as March 12,2014 then my end date should be able to choose same date March 12,2014 and future dates from March 12,2014.

So, I used the below code to validate:

```
<input type="text" class="validate[required,dateRange[grp1],custom[date] text-input datepicker"   name="daterange" id="start_date" value="">
<input type="text" class="validate[required,dateRange[grp1],custom[date] text-input datepicker" name="daterange" id="end_date" value="">
```

However, the above code is not validating for the same day.

Also done all the methods in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339338/start-and-end-date-validation-using-jquery-validation-engine-js . However, nothing worked for me??